# Remote Write Protection from the Winbond UEFI Chip

Tags: windows, uefi

I try to enable the Intel DCI on my Lenovo Thinkpad X270 (Windows 11). Because of that i use the Tool Chipsec to get the Offset for the UEFI Variables. Then i want to change them with the tool ru.efi. Every Time i want so save the change, there is the error message: Write variable failed.

There is a write protection in the BIOS. I already used the tool Chipsec to enable the write protection, but that doesnt work. Because of tha i created a bin file with the As Programmer and the CH341A. But now i need some help, i dont know how to remove the write protection of the UEFI with the hardware.

Thanks a lot for your help!

I have alredy tired the Tool Chipsec and the tool ru.efi. But nothing of them work. I created a bin with an SPI Programmer, but no i`dont know but now how to proceed further.